# Extract a perticular line from log files

Tags: command-line, grep

I have a log file like below,

```
 - UTT (1): test_1978_recreatie_1656.wav
lattice-to-ctm-conf ark:- output/spk001_test_1978_recreatie_1656_1bestsym.ctm 
online2-wav-nnet3-latgen-faster --online=false --do-endpointing=false --frame-subsampling-factor=3 --config=exp/tdnn1a_sp_bi_online/conf/online.conf --max-active=7000 --beam=15.0 --lattice-beam=6.0 --acoustic-scale=1.0 --word-symbol-table=exp/tdnn1a_sp_bi_online/graph_s/words.txt exp/tdnn1a_sp_bi_online/final.mdl exp/tdnn1a_sp_bi_online/graph_s/HCLG.fst 'ark:echo spk001 test_1978_recreatie_1656|' 'scp:echo test_1978_recreatie_1656 raw_data/spk001/test_1978_recreatie_1656.wav|' ark:- 
test_1978_recreatie_1656 wij zullen <unk> 
LOG (online2-wav-nnet3-latgen-faster[5.5.929~1-9bca2]:main():online2-wav-nnet3-latgen-faster.cc:296) Decoded utterance test_1978_recreatie_1656
LOG (lattice-to-ctm-conf[5.5.929~1-9bca2]:main():lattice-to-ctm-conf.cc:175) For utterance test_1978_recreatie_1656, Bayes Risk 4.06451, avg. confidence per-word 0.636305
 - UTT (1): test_1978_recreatie_1656.wav, time: 1 seconds
 - UTT (2): test_1978_recreatie_1657.wav
lattice-to-ctm-conf ark:- output/spk001_test_1978_recreatie_1657_1bestsym.ctm 
online2-wav-nnet3-latgen-faster --online=false --do-endpointing=false --frame-subsampling-factor=3 --config=exp/tdnn1a_sp_bi_online/conf/online.conf --max-active=7000 --beam=15.0 --lattice-beam=6.0 --acoustic-scale=1.0 --word-symbol-table=exp/tdnn1a_sp_bi_online/graph_s/words.txt exp/tdnn1a_sp_bi_online/final.mdl exp/tdnn1a_sp_bi_online/graph_s/HCLG.fst 'ark:echo spk001 test_1978_recreatie_1657|' 'scp:echo test_1978_recreatie_1657 raw_data/spk001/test_1978_recreatie_1657.wav|' ark:- 
test_1978_recreatie_1657 we kunnen dat wel zeggen 
LOG (online2-wav-nnet3-latgen-faster[5.5.929~1-9bca2]:main():online2-wav-nnet3-latgen-faster.cc:296) Decoded utterance test_1978_recreatie_1657
LOG (lattice-to-ctm-conf[5.5.929~1-9bca2]:main():lattice-to-ctm-conf.cc:175) For utterance test_1978_recreatie_1657, Bayes Risk 0.654865, avg. confidence per-word 0.922916
 - UTT (2): test_1978_recreatie_1657.wav, time: 0 seconds
```

In the log file, at each 4th line from UTT(n) there is a transcription, which I want to extract by using the Linux command. For example `test_1978_recreatie_1657 we kunnen dat wel zeggen` and `test_1978_recreatie_1656 wij zullen <unk>`    Earlier I was looking for the grep command for particular pattern extraction but it did not work out. Please suggest how can I do it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what lines you want to match. Is it every 4th line after `UTT(N)`? That doesn't make sense with the input you show since you have cases with 2 `UTT(N)` lines one after the other. What output are you expecting here? What `grep` command did you try?

Comment: Do you just want the first of each pair of LOG lines. Please edit your question to make clear what you need.

Answer (score 3):

I think that what you're asking is to print the fourth line after any occurrence of `UTT (n)`, resetting the counter to 1 each time you encounter `UTT (n)`:

```
awk '/UTT \([0-9]+\)/{line=0} {line++} line==4' file
```

Output

```
test_1978_recreatie_1656 wij zullen <unk>
test_1978_recreatie_1657 we kunnen dat wel zeggen
```

Some explanation. `awk` has lines of the form `pattern {action}`, where either `pattern` or `action` are optional (but not both). Each line of input is applied to all pattern/action instructions in sequence. A missing pattern implies that the action will be executed for every input line. A missing `action` implies that the input line will be printed.

```
/UTT \([0-9]+\)/ {line=0}    # Match the pattern to set line=0
{line++}                     # Each line of input increments line
line==4                      # When line==4, implicitly print the line
```

Comment: That's a nice explanation, however if there were 4 or more lines before the first UTT line, this would print the 4th line (although this isn't a problem for the example input).

Comment: @rowboat could address this with `{line++}` being replaced by `line > "" {line++}`

Answer (score 2):

Awk may be simpler than grep for something like this.

```bsh
awk 'c && !--c; $2 == "UTT" {c=3}' file
```

This sets a counter whenever a "UTT" line matched. If the counter is set, decrement the variable and print the line if the counter is back to zero. You could match "UTT" lines in various ways, e.g. a regex `/^ - UTT/ {c=3}` or string match `index($0, " - UTT") == 1 {c=3}`. The condition `$2 == "UTT"` matches when the second field is the string "UTT".

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/UTT/{a=NR+3} NR==a' input
```

In this command, if `UTT` is found then `a` is set to `NR+3`. `NR==a` prints the required output.